# How do I add myself back to the dropdown list for assigning a card in an Azure DevOps board?

Tags: azure-devops

I accidentally clicked the red X next to my name and now I have to manually search for myself every time I want to assign a card to myself. How do I put my name back in the dropdown list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh there we go, I just had to search for myself a few times and then my name started appearing in the list again!

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes it slips my mind because I go to accept it and it says I'm not allowed to yet... :)